# using xstring to obtain lead author's last name from authblk in a class file

Tags: documentclass-writing, xstring, authblk

I would like to query the last name of the first author of an article and then put it into the header. I use \StrBetween on the \AB@authlist macro to get the part of the string between the first space and the first comma, which results in a strange output due to the author marker ($^1$). What is the correct final character so that the command returns only the author last name?
I want to pass this from the .cls file, though I have added a .tex MWE to demonstrate the problem, below.

MWE .cls:

```
   \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{chkcls}[2020/08/25 v0 class]
\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,10pt}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts,amsbsy,authblk,xstring}
\newcommand {\leadauthor} {
\StrBetween[1,1]{\AB@authlist,}{ }{,}\par
}
\endinput
```

MWE .tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{chkcls}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsbsy,authblk,xstring}
\begin{document}
\title{A funny title} 
\author[1]{First Author}
  \author[2]{Second author}  
  \author[3]{Third author} 
\affil[1]{first.author@uni.de, Germany} 
\affil[2]{second.author@uni.es, Spain} 
\affil[3]{third.author@uni.no, Norway} 
\maketitle
Some text in the document
\leadauthor
\end{document}
```

Currently results in : `Author101012.0pt12.0pt1`